# How can I prepare lots of code to be printed on a long scroll?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

### What I'm trying to do:

I have lots of software code that I need to print on a long scroll. The scroll will be no more than 440mm wide and as long as it needs to be (with a maximum of 45m). The resulting code listing is to be part of [an exhibit](http://www.praxisandpoetics.org/researchthroughdesign/) contrasting the ‘sketching’ phase in a multidisciplinary project between design, social science, and software engineering.

### What I've tried:

#### • Printing straight from the IDE

I cannot print straight from the development environment (Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server Management Studio) because:

- Both tools assume standard page sizes
- I need to rotate the software code listing 180 degrees so that the end of the listing is at the tail of the paper roll.

#### • Using Photoshop

Since, I can't print from the IDE, I’m doing it in Adobe Photoshop (CS5, 64 bit, on Windows 8). My workflow for this is verging on the ridiculous:

1. First I cut-and-paste each file from the code editor into a Microsoft Word document. If I cut-and-paste the code listings into PS/Ai [I lose the formatting](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/how_could_i_paste_a_rtf_pdf_word_text_keeping_the_formatting_into_photoshop) (for example the coloring of comments differently form variable declarations)
2. I save the Microsoft Word document as a PDF and open that into Photoshop (to preserve the formatting)
3. I now have 51 PSD files, each with one layer containing the text for that ‘page’. It’s rasterized layers as it is not editable as text
4. Using Adobe Bridge I open all 51 PSD files created in step 3 and “Load Files into Photoshop Layers” so that I have a new single Photoshop file with all 51 text image layers in.
5. The layers sit on top of each other. What I need is for them to sit head-to-toe. I don’t know how to do this without spending a million years selecting layers and moving them by hand.
6. If I ever get Stage 5 done I will then group the 51 layers and rotate the result through 180 degrees.
7. I will then re-size the result to have a width of 400mm and print the resulting file on our banner printer, having first calculated the resulting paper ‘height’ and turned off the automatic paper cutting.

### My Questions:

- Is there a better way of doing this?
- I can see the Photoshop actions that will align layers by their tops, their bottoms, or their centers but how do I automatically align them so that the bottom of layer 1 touches the top of layer 2, the bottom of layer 2 touches the top of layer 3, etc.?

Comment: John - your Illustrator answer below looks perfect. I'll give that a go and report back. I think I can get around the Illustrator size restrictions by keeping each file separate and letting the printer run them together by not cutting the paper roll between prints.

Comment: I know I'm a bit late to the party, but there's also a handy [question on tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264389/typesetting-an-infinite-page) about a very similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using Illustrator

You're on the right track, but Photoshop is not the way to go for huge files like this. Illustrator will be able to handle text much better.

#### The Good News

You can import formatted text into Illustrator! (steps below)

#### The Bad News

You're going to run into a road block: the maximum document dimensions (in CS5 at least) is 5779.55mm. I don't know how long your banner is actually going to be, but that's about 39m shorter than your specified maximum print size.

#### The Steps:

*So*, if your code will all fit in a 5.7m document:

1. Paste your code from the code editor into Word (as you have done previously)
2. Save it as a Rich Text Format (RTF) document<sup>†</sup>
3. Open the RTF document in Illustrator
4. Your text will be clipped in a shape, but you can re-size the shape as necessary

The result will be editable text in Illustrator that maintains the IDE code formatting:

[image: result in Illustrator]

<sup><sup>†</sup> Note: Illustrator *can* open native Word files (.doc/docx), but this gave me some weird newline issues. Your results may vary.</sup>

---

### Using a PDF printer (maybe)

If you have Adobe Acrobat (or similar PDF printer), you should be able to print your document with a custom page size. The dialog is a little hard to get to, but it should look something like this:

[image: Custom page size dialog]

This is how I got there:

1. **File** → ***Print*** (in Visual Studio)
2. Select ***Adobe PDF*** as the printer (from the dropdown)
3. Click ***Properties***
4. From the **Paper/Quality** tab, click ***Advanced***
5. In the **Paper Size** dropdown, select ***PostScript Custom Page Size***

#### The Good News:

You'll be able to select a very long height, up to 635 meters!

#### The Bad News:

Printing from Visual Studio may or may not preserve the text formatting. I only have VS2010 express, where this [is not a feature](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2018079c-4896-45b2-affd-6620483c88e6/printing-source-code-with-syntax-coloring). However, it might work for you in VS2012.